# Local admin access for users to their own machines

Tags: linux, windows

Is anyone aware of a way to allow a group of users, local admin access to their own machines?

Is there a high level way of doing this?

Don't really want to go round to 300+ machines to do this manually..

Windows AD environment, users who need local admin have a range of Windows 7, 10 and Linux Mint, Ubuntu.

*NOTE* 
I don't want to give them local admin to all machines on the network, just for them to have local admin over their own machine and no one elses 
*/NOTE*

Comment: That's might be what you want to try: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1953316-gpo-local-admin-to-user-based-on-computer-owner-in-ad

Comment: That looks pretty good, i've give that a go :)